# ParseStarterProject : SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

I have tried to open ParseStarterProject which is demo application by [Parse](https://www.parse.com/)

I opened project in Android Studio and got this error :

```
SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

I have checked my **local.properties** file and path is correct over there which is :

```
## This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
#Thu Sep 17 12:01:30 IST 2015
ndk.dir=E\:\\android-sdk\\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=E\:\\android-sdk
```

Also I checked from File -> Project structure -> SDK Location contains same sdk path.

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry that again I am posting answer of question asked by my own but I got solution :

[Here](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart?onboard=#parse_data/mobile/android/native/new) parse documents mentioned that To open a project in Android studio using **File -> Open**.

[image]

But do not open project directly but import this project as **File -> Import Project** then all gradle setting will be done.

Thanks .!!